# retrieving username and password in java from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

please help i want to know how to compare user entered username and password in textfields from mysql database.....i am using netbeans IDE
**here's my code:**

```
String a,b;
    a=txtusername.getText();
    b=new String(txtpassword.getPassword());
    try
    {
        Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
        Connection conn=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection
                 ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root","pizza123");
        Statement stmt=(Statement) conn.createStatement();
        String query1="select username from userdata where username='"+a+"';";
        String query2="select password from userdata where password='"+b+"';";
        ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery(query1);
        ResultSet rs2=stmt.executeQuery(query2);
        if(a.equals(rs1.getString(query1)) || b.equals(rs2.getString(query2)))
        {
             close();
             tickets x= new tickets();
             x.setVisible(true);
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Username or Password is incorrect");
        }
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | HeadlessException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: change your query like , "Select * from userdata Where username='" + a + "' and password='"b "'";

Answer (score 0):

Send a query to the database

```
SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE username = @username, password = @password;
```

User parameters to add the values for `@username and @ password`, otherwise its posible to use sql injection. If infected rows > 0 then you got a succesful login

Answer (score 0):

The statements rs1.getString(query1) and rs2.getString(query2) cannot work.
From a result set object you can retrieve its current row values using column index or column names.
In your case you could have written rs1.getString("username") or rs1.getString(1) because in JDBC world indexes begin at one.

Anyway a better solution could be this

```
String a,b;
a = txtusername.getText();
b = new String(txtpassword.getPassword());

PreparedStatement statement = null;
Connection conn = null;

try {

    Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
    Connection conn=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root","pizza123");

    String query = "select * from userdata where username = ? and password = ?";
    statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);

    statement.setString(1, a);
    statement.setString(2, b);

    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

    //check if you have found a valid row
    if(rs.next()) {

         close();
         tickets x= new tickets();
         x.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Username or Password is incorrect");
    }
} catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | HeadlessException e) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());

} finally {

      try {

         if(statement != null)
            statement.close();

      } catch (SQLException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
      }

      try {

         if(conn != null)
            conn.close();

      } catch (SQLException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

}

This solution uses PreparedStatement to prevent SQLInjection attacks. Using a finally block you are sure to release the statement and the connection.

Comment: How come both of these two lines contains a 1     statement.setString(1, a);
    statement.setString(1, b);

Comment: I think one should be 1 and another 2 or 2 and 3 I wonder if I make sense